# Block does not appear when using custom type, but appears with core/template

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, layout-update

New to Magento. Trying to write a custom block and just make it show up at the most basic level. Been going crazy for two days, comparing my work to those of the other modules we are using plus research.

**I think** the issue lies somewhere with Magento not recognizing the block as being part of the global config. **I need** the block just to appear when I place it in `local.xml`!

At `app\code\local\Csos\Spuritem\etc\config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Csos_Spuritem>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Csos_Spuritem>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <spuritem>
                <class>Csos_Spuritem_Block</class>
            </spuritem>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

The block definition `app\code\local\Csos\Spuritem\Block\Item.php`:

```
<?php

class Csos_Spuritem_Block_Item extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract {

}
```

*When I use* `print_r(Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->xpath('//global//blocks'));` shows that my module is active:

```
[spuritem] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                (
                    [class] => Csos_Spuritem_Block
                )
```

In `frontend\base\default\layout\local.xml`,

```
<layout version="1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="spuritem/item" name="spuritem.forever" template="csos/spuritem/spuritem.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="showit" template="csos/showme.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

and finally, `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\csos\spuritem\spuritem.phtml`

```
<h1 id="spuritem">This is where my stuff will go.</h1>
```

In the current state, this produces nothing on the homepage. **However**, if in the `local.xml` I change

I have allowed block permissions in the back end for "spuritem/item".

`<block type="spuritem/item" name="spuritem.forever" template="csos/spuritem"/>`

to

`<block type="core/templatem" name="spuritem.forever" template="csos/spuritem"/>`

The homepage will produce the text as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your block to extend from `Mage_Core_Block_Template` and not from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`. In `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::_toHtml()` looks like this

```
/**
 * Override this method in descendants to produce html
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml()
{
    return '';
}
```

So your block is rendered but the output is empty string. `Mage_Core_Block_Template` has the following code which renders the template file:

```
/**
 * Render block HTML
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
        return '';
    }
    $html = $this->renderView();
    return $html;
}
```

Alternatively you can create `_toHtml()` method in your block and prepare your own code for rendering content in case default one is for some reasons not suitable.